# Elastic Update By Query Updated Entire Index Instead

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-7

I am trying to get a query to work that will update a specific field in a document, provided it matches a query (in this example, where one field matches an exact value).

Here I am trying to query all documents that have the field "Foo" set to "Bar", and set the field "TextField5" in each of them to 1337. There are only a handfull in the index that match this. However, when I run this query, **every document in the index** has its TextField5 updated.

```
POST /threat_vuln/_update_by_query
{
  "query": { 
    "match": {
      "Foo": "Bar"
    }
  },
  
  "script" : {
    "source" : "ctx._source.TextField5='1337';",
    "lang" : "painless"
  }
}
```

I've gone over the [Update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) and [Update By Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) and am still missing something. How can I change this to only update documents that match the query?

I'm on Kibana 7.4.0

EDIT: Also tried this, which still updates every document in the index instead of those matching the query:

```
POST /threat_vuln/_update_by_query
{
  "query": { 
    "bool" : {
      "must": [
                  {
                      "match": {
                            "Foo": "Bar"
                          }
                    }
              ]
      }
  },
  
  "script" : {
    "source" : "ctx._source.TextField5='1337';",
    "lang" : "painless"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work as intended:

```
POST /threat_vuln/_update_by_query
{
  "query": { 
    "bool" : {
      "must": [
                  {
                      "match": {
                            "Foo.keyword": "Bar"
                          }
                    }
              ]
      }
  },
  
  "script" : {
    "source" : "ctx._source.TextField5='1337';",
    "lang" : "painless"
  }
}
```

I still don't understand how/why the examples in the question would just go ahead and update everything with what now appears to be a query that should return nothing, but I digress.

Comment: Have you tried your different queries on the `_search` endpoint first? What did they return?